# Error happend when using "with as " and "listagg" in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have run sql as below, but an error arised, anybody could help me?

```
with t
as (
select 'a' as p,'a' as n from dual
union 
select 'b','a' from dual
union 
select 'c','a' from dual
union 
select 'd','b' from dual
union 
select 'e','b' from dual
union 
select 'f','b' from dual
)
select listagg(p,',') within group(order by n) from t
```

Thanks.

Comment: Your code works without problems on 11gR2. Are you trying to run it on an earlier Oracle version? This won't work, because listagg() was added in 11gR2

Comment: Thanks, Frank you are right. Mine is 10.2.0.1.0, and I have test it successful on 11g.

Comment: @VikiYang - Use `select n, wm_concat(p) from t group by n`

Comment: To unnamed-horse: "ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected" in 10G, but it works in 11G

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff en, but I think it's more flexible than wm_concat.

Comment: @VikiYang - it isn't more flexible if it isn't available in the version you're using. [There are other alternatives though](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/string-aggregation-techniques.php).

Comment: @VikiYang you can see my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have `listagg` in Oracle 10G. Either try it in Oracle 11GR2 as Frank mentioned. It works fine without any errors.

OR there are some alternatives like `wm_concat` or `xmlagg`.

I personally prefer `xmlagg` function over `wm_concat`